# Apache won't honour my .htaccess after sending http response 400 from PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

After examining the arguments in the URI (in the PHP code of an exising page) I like to have Apache redirect to an error page returning a 400 error to the user if the arguments have an error.

However, Apache seems to ignore my `ErrorDocument` directives in .htaccess when I send an HTTP 400 response header from PHP, using `http_response_code()`.

The `ErrorDocument 404` does work (so in principle Apache is configured OK on this point, I assume), but only when I try to visit an non-existing page. Issuing a 400, 404 or 500 response header is seemingly ignored by Apache, although my browser gets an (empty) page with the response code I intended to send, so no problem there.

How can I tell Apache (or PHP) to use the `.htaccess` file in these cases?

> PHP code generating the status header

```
$req = array_key_exists("req", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["req"] : "";
switch (strtolower($req)) { 
    case "a": $request = "add"; 
        break; 

    case "e": $request = "edit"; 
        break; 

    case "v": $request = "view"; 
        break; 

    case "d": http_response_code(501); // Not Implemented. 
        exit; 

    default: http_response_code(400); 
        exit;
}
```

Comment: How are you sending this header... can you show the code

Comment: `$req = array_key_exists("req", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["req"] : "";
switch (strtolower($req))
{
case "a":
    $request = "add";
    break;  
case "e":
    $request = "edit"; 
    break;  
case "v":
    $request = "view"; 
    break;  
case "d":
    http_response_code(501);        // Not Implemented.
    exit;   
default:
    http_response_code(400);
    exit;   
}`

Comment: Of course just issuing a 404 response code from within your script is not going to trigger the normal Apache mechanism for such a case ... this isn’t an actual “Apache 404”, because your PHP script _was found_ without any problems. (Same for the other status codes you mentioned, 404 just as example.) You could simply have your PHP script include your 404 error document file in this situation, if the goal is to get the same output ..

Comment: @CBroe: I am not talking about a 404, but a 400 or 500 instead.

Comment: @Dandorid — Unsurprisingly, other error statuses work *in exactly the same way*.

Comment: Thing is, it wasn't a bad request from the servers point of view so it gets passed to your php script where you have decided its a bad request and set a 400 header, you can also include your error document and it will be sent in the response

Comment: So what you are saying, from a PHP standpoint, it does not make much sense to return a 400, because you have to do your own error page handling anyway.

Comment: _“I am not talking about a 404, but a 400 or 500 instead”_ - same difference. Fact is, this is not an _actual_ error on the web server level, so the web server has no inclination to react to this in the way it would normally do either.

Comment: _“So what you are saying, from a PHP standpoint, it does not make much sense to return a 400, because you have to do your own error page handling anyway.”_ - no, no one is saying that. What we are saying is, if you decide to issue any such error code in your script logic, then you have to specify what response body you want to send there as well. You are simply “past” the part where Apache is responsible for handling this here. It has passed control over to your PHP script.

Comment: Okay, I get it.

Answer (score 2):

At the point where your script is called Apache is no longer involved in the interaction between the browser and the web server. As far as Apache is concerned the request was valid and your script was called.

Simply returning a response code to the browser is exactly that. Just a response code and Apache on your server is not involved in that in any way.

The 404 works because Apache is the one who is detecting something missing and returns the error and whatever is in the error document. Your script never gets called in that case.